# If function based on query function results

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can you wrap a query function with an if function?

My query can produce 3 results, yes yes, yes no, no no. These results occur in two different cells. I want the if function to then say - yes yes - true and either of the other results false. When doing it simply it just gives an error.

Comment: Could you show what your sheet looks like? From pure text it's hard to figure out what is actually happening there :-)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result or share a formula you use and gives you error

Comment: =query((IMPORTRANGE("https://.....","Nokia 2020!A1:K200")), "select Col7 where Col1 = '"&A5&"' and Col2 = '"&E5&"'",0) this is the original query function where is produces 2 cell results yes yes

Comment: I can't add an image to show what the result looks like. I created a dummy version of it at this link to try to give a better idea https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C5xWlw9vMZMNhXprSCBZsNp0T9qMxvuooIP8I6JoI2Y/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please give the public permissions to view this file.

Comment: I made it public now

Comment: would an array help? I tried making the formula this =if((query((IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.g....","Sheet 2020!A1:K200")), "select Col7 where Col1 = '"&A4&"' and Col2 = '"&E4&"'",-4))={"Yes";"No"},TRUE,FALSE) . I still have not achieved the results I want but I am not sure if I am on the right track or not

Comment: I am sorry, even after seeing the sheet I cannot quite understand what you want to do. If you to use an `if` function, you should do so - I cannot see any `if` function in your cell formula as it is and your query seems not to work even without it.

Comment: ok I fixed the formula, i am used to writing the query function with an imported range which uses labeling of "col1" instead of A - so now the results are produced in column J where you see it says yes in cell J2 & J3. I would like to wrap the formula in an if function so it said true if this occurs and false if any other combination comes up

Answer (score 0):

### Wrapping of formulas

- The `IF` formula has the syntax `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`
- Thereby, the logical expression can be a comparison of values, e.g `IF(value="Yes", TRUE, FALSE)`
- value can be in this case either

  - a fixed value, e.g. a string
  - a cell reference, e.g. `IF(J2="Yes", TRUE, FALSE)`
  - a nested formula, which can a query
- In your case, you are interested in the latter, so:

`=IF(query(Sheet2!A1:J7,"select G where A = '"&A2&"' and '"&E2&"' = B",0)="Yes", TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: This won't work because the result from my query has 2 results with 3 possible out puts - yes yes, yes no, no no. If the result is yes no then the above formula would still read true in which case i want it to read false. The primary issue is that the results occupy 2 different cells.

Comment: I think I see now what you mean. Maybe the formula `=IF(and(J2="Yes", J3="Yes"), TRUE, FALSE)` what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an answer with using the IFS function =ifs(query(Sheet2!A3:J9,"select G where A = '"&A4&"' and '"&E4&"' = B",0)="yes","TRUE",query(Sheet2!A3:J9,"select G where A = '"&A4&"' and '"&E4&"' = B",0)="no","FALSE")

That was able to solve the issue that the simple if function could not solve

Comment: ***This still is not solving the issue if the results are Yes No, it is still only reading the yes as true and ignoring the second output